# I don't know how to fix this error: reached end of file while parsing

Tags: java

When running this code, I keep getting the same error, I thought the I fixed the error with the brackets, but I was wrong.

```
public class INCOME {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
int income = 4001;
if (income > 3000) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Income is greater than 3000");
}
else if (income > 4000) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Income is greater than 4000");
}
else if (income > 5000) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Income is greater than 5000");

}
}
```

error is

```
INCOME.java:15: error: reached end of file while parsing
```

Comment: You're missing a closing curly brace. Indent your code properly, and you'll see where it's missing.

Comment: Note: I rolled back the last edit, because the edit destroyed the question.  The edit improved the look and feel of the question, as desired, and in addition added the curly brace that was missing.  The last edit took away the entire point of the question, and would have made the answerers look bad.  Also, the reason for the problem was that the OP didn't use proper indentation; prettying up the indentation defeated this aspect of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a curly brace, it should run fine after you add one.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class INCOME {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int income = 4001;
    if (income > 3000) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Income is greater than 3000");
    } else if (income > 4000) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Income is greater than 4000");
    } else if (income > 5000) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Income is greater than 5000");

    }
}
} //This guy here :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two closing braces at the end. The second to last closes the `else if`. The last one closes the `main`, therefore there is nothing closing the class `INCOME`. Add one more brace at the end `}`. Also, swap your tests. Because `5000` and `4000` are **both** greater than `3000`. So the first test will be true.

```
public class INCOME {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int income = 4001;
        if (income > 5000) { // <-- first.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Income is greater than 5000");
        } else if (income > 4000) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Income is greater than 4000");
        } else if (income > 3000) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Income is greater than 3000");
        }
    } // <-- this is the last brace in your code.
} // <-- you don't have this one.
```